# django/python | Get files from database, zip, then send to browser

Tags: python, django

Please help me with my problem.

I'm sorry if this sounds noobie, coz I really am. There are files (jpg, docs) in a certain database, how would I select those file in the database, save them in a zip file, then send over to the browser as HttpResponse or something like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=group.zip'
```

The part which greatly bothers me is when taking the files from the database coz Google doesn't seem to be helpful at that.

Some of the relevant codes I have are these:

```
temp = request.POST.getlist('cbox') #cbox is the field in form
tempx = models.FileTable.objects.filter(pk__in = temp)
```

I no longer know what to do from here. Thanks in advance! :p

Comment: I found this code, but i have variety of file type.
    files = []
    for thing in Thing.objects.all():
        files.append(("%s.pdf" % (thing.id,), thing.biggish_file()))
    buffer = StringIO()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for name, f in files:
        zip.writestr(name, f)
    zip.close()
    buffer.flush()
    ret_zip = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    response.write(ret_zip)
    return response

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) and [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html). Create a `StringIO`, open it as a `ZipFile`, add files to it, then [send it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#usage).

Comment: I think this is an easy approach, but since I am new with python, I really don't know how to do this. :(